# Why doesn't '??' run help.search() when using ESS?

Tags: r, ess

On my windows machine at work, when I type `??topic` in the R terminal using ESS, I don't get the expected result of `help.search(topic)`, instead I get a new buffer titled `*help[R](?topic)*`, with contents:

```
No documentation for '?topic' in specified packages and libraries:
you could try '???topic'
```

My google-fu has failed me so far in finding the cause, but I'm sure someone else has sorted this out by now. What do I need to change in my configuration to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been sorted out for quite some time in ESS. Try upgrading.

With the new version of ESS you can get the same behavior with <kbd>C-c C-d C-a</kbd> which stands for `apropos`.